# Hide / show in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to hide all divs and display only those which are connected with "button". What's happening is only last div is visible - no matter witch div(as a button) was clicked.

EDIT: Whole html:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
  <style type='text/css'>
   html, body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
     overflow: visible;
}


.container {
    margin:20px;
}

.mark:hover{  cursor: move; -webkit-opacity: 1; }
.mark{   overflow: visible; float:left; width: 50px; height: 50px; padding-left: 10px; cursor: move; position: relative; left: 50px; border: 0px solid black; -webkit-opacity: 0.25; }
input { margin-left: 50px; overflow: visible;}

.del {visibility: hidden;}
.mark:hover:before > .del {visibility: visible; cursor: pointer; position: relative; left: 35px; content: '*', font-weight: bold;}

.color_picker, #slider{ position: relative; float: right;}
#slider1 { margin-top: 10px;}

  #red1, #green1, #blue1,
  #red2, #green2, #blue2,
  #red3, #green3, #blue3,
  #red4, #green4, #blue4,
  #red5, #green5, #blue5,
  #red6, #green6, #blue6,
  #red7, #green7, #blue7,
  #slider1, #slider2, #slider3, #slider4, #slider5, #slider6 {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 3px;
  }

  #size1, #red1 .ui-slider-range, #red2 .ui-slider-range, #red3 .ui-slider-range, #red4 .ui-slider-range, #red5 .ui-slider-range, #red6 .ui-slider-range, #red7 .ui-slider-range, #red8 .ui-slider-range { background: #ef2929;}
  #red1 .ui-slider-handle, #red2 .ui-slider-handle, #red3 .ui-slider-handle, #red4 .ui-slider-handle, #red5 .ui-slider-handle, #red6 .ui-slider-handle, #red7 .ui-slider-handle, #red8 .ui-slider-handle { border-color: #ef2929; }
  #green1 .ui-slider-range, #green2 .ui-slider-range, #green3 .ui-slider-range, #green4 .ui-slider-range, #green5 .ui-slider-range, #green6 .ui-slider-range, #green7 .ui-slider-range, #green8 .ui-slider-range { background: #8ae234; }
  #green1 .ui-slider-handle, #green2 .ui-slider-handle, #green3 .ui-slider-handle, #green4 .ui-slider-handle, #green5 .ui-slider-handle, #green6 .ui-slider-handle, #green7 .ui-slider-handle, #green8 .ui-slider-handle { border-color: #8ae234; }
  #blue1 .ui-slider-range, #blue2 .ui-slider-range, #blue3 .ui-slider-range, #blue4 .ui-slider-range, #blue5 .ui-slider-range, #blue6 .ui-slider-range, #blue7 .ui-slider-range, #blue8 .ui-slider-range { background: #729fcf; }
  #blue1 .ui-slider-handle, #blue2 .ui-slider-handle, #blue3 .ui-slider-handle, #blue4 .ui-slider-handle, #blue5 .ui-slider-handle #blue6 .ui-slider-handle, #blue7 .ui-slider-handle, #blue8 .ui-slider-handle { border-color: #729fcf; }

.da_font{
 width: 1000%;
background: transparent !important;
 
}

.rel{ display: none;}
</style>
<script>  

  $(document).ready(function () {
   
    function hexFromRGB(r, g, b) {
    var hex = [
      r.toString( 16 ),
      g.toString( 16 ),
      b.toString( 16 )
    ];
    $.each( hex, function( nr, val ) {
      if ( val.length === 1 ) {
        hex[ nr ] = "0" + val;
      }
    });
    return hex.join( "" ).toUpperCase();
  };

 var i = 0;
    $('.container').on('click', '.dodaj', function () {
    i++;    
        $('<div class="mark ui-widget-content klik'+i+'" ><div class="ui-state-active da_font swatch'+i+'" contenteditable="true">Sample text</div><div class=del>*</div></div>').appendTo('.container').draggable();
        $('<div class="rel" id="red_val'+i+'"></div><div class="rel" id="red'+i+'" data-number="'+i+'"></div><div class="rel" id="green'+i+'" data-number="'+i+'"></div><div class="rel" id="blue'+i+'" data-number="'+i+'"></div><div class="rel" id="slider'+i+'"  data-number="'+i+'" class="ui-slider"></div>').appendTo('.color_picker');


        $(function() {
     $('.da_font').resizable();
   });
    
    $( ".klik"+i ).click(function() {
     
    $( ".rel" ).css("display", "none");
    $( "#red_val"+i ).css("display", "inline");
   $( "#red"+i ).css("display", "inline");
   $( "#green"+i ).css("display", "inline");
   $( "#blue"+i ).css("display", "inline");
   $( "#slider"+i ).css("display", "inline");
  });

      $( "#slider"+i ).slider({
      value:100,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      step: 1,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
      
   var element = ui.handle;
      element = $(element);
      var i = element.closest(".ui-slider").attr("data-number");
      $( ".swatch"+i ).css( "font-size", ui.value );
      }
      });
  
      $("#red"+ i + ", #green"+i + ", #blue"+i).slider({
      orientation: "horizontal",
      range: "min",
      max: 255,
      value: 127,
      slide: refreshSwatch,
      change: refreshSwatch
      });


    $( "#red"+i ).slider( "value", 255 );
    $( "#green"+i ).slider( "value", 140 );
    $( "#blue"+i ).slider( "value", 60 );

});

   function refreshSwatch(event, ui ) {

      var element = ui.handle;
      element = $(element);
      var i = element.closest(".ui-slider").attr("data-number");
      var red = $( "#red"+i ).slider( "value" ),
      green = $( "#green"+i ).slider( "value" ),
      blue = $( "#blue"+i ).slider( "value" ),
      hex = hexFromRGB( red, green, blue );
      $( ".swatch"+i ).css( "color", "#" + hex );
      $( "#red_val"+i ).text( "#" + hex );
  }

 });

  $(document).ready(function edit() {
 
    $('.container').on('click', '.ukryj', function x() {
        $('.mark').css({"opacity":"1", "visibility":"hidden"});
        $('.del').css("visibility","hidden");
        $('.ui-state-active').css({"visibility":"visible", "border":"0px solid black"});

    });
    
    $('.container').on('click', '.pokaz', function () {

        $('.mark').css({"opacity":"", "visibility":""});
        $('.del').css("visibility","");
        $('.ui-state-active').css({"visibility":"", "border":""});


    });
    
      $('.container').on('click', '.del', function () {  
      $(this).parent('.mark').css("visibility", "hidden");
      $(this).css("visibility", "hidden");
     $( "#red"+i ).css( "value", 255 );
     $( "#green"+i ).css( "value", 140 );
     $( "#blue"+i ).slider( "value", 60 );
    });
          
    
});
</script>
   <script>


  </script> 

<body>


<div class="container">
 <div class="menu">
<div class="dodaj">Add input</div> <div class="ukryj">Hide input</div> <div class="pokaz">Show</div>
</div>
<div class="color_picker">
</div>


</div>
</body>

asdsdfs sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsd sdfsdffsf
```

Comment: why do you have multiple versions of jQuery

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the use of a closure variable in a loop like scenario, the variable `i` is shared between all the click handlers

```
var i = 0;
$('.container').on('click', '.dodaj', function () {
    i++;
    var $mark = $('<div class="mark ui-widget-content klik" data-number="' + i + '"><div class="ui-state-active da_font swatch" contenteditable="true">Sample text</div><div class=del>*</div></div>').appendTo('.container').draggable();
    $('<div class="rel red_val" data-number="' + i + '"></div><div class="rel red" data-number="' + i + '"></div><div class="rel green" data-number="' + i + '"></div><div class="rel blue" data-number="' + i + '"></div><div class="rel slider ui-slider" data-number="' + i + '"></div>').appendTo('.color_picker');
    $mark.find('.da_font').resizable();
});

$('.container').on('click', '.klik', function(){
    $(".rel").hide();
    $('.rel[data-number="'+$(this).data('number')+'"]').css("display", "inline");
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function hexFromRGB(r, g, b) {
    var hex = [
      r.toString(16),
      g.toString(16),
      b.toString(16)
    ];
    $.each(hex, function(nr, val) {
      if (val.length === 1) {
        hex[nr] = "0" + val;
      }
    });
    return hex.join("").toUpperCase();
  };

  var i = 0;
  $('.container').on('click', '.dodaj', function() {
    i++;
    var $mark = $('<div class="mark ui-widget-content klik" data-number="' + i + '"><div class="ui-state-active da_font swatch" contenteditable="true">Sample text</div><div class=del>*</div></div>').appendTo('.container').draggable();
    var $rel = $('<div class="rel-ct" data-number="' + i + '"><div class="rel red_val" data-number="' + i + '"></div><div class="rel red" data-number="' + i + '"></div><div class="rel green" data-number="' + i + '"></div><div class="rel blue" data-number="' + i + '"></div><div class="rel slider ui-slider" data-number="' + i + '"></div></div>').appendTo('.color_picker');

    $mark.find('.da_font').resizable();


    $rel.find(".slider").slider({
      value: 100,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      step: 1,
      slide: function(event, ui) {
        $(ui.handle).closest('.rel-ct').find(".swatch").css("font-size", ui.value);
      }
    });

    $rel.find(".red, .green, .blue").slider({
      orientation: "horizontal",
      range: "min",
      max: 255,
      value: 127,
      slide: refreshSwatch,
      change: refreshSwatch
    });


    $rel.find(".red").slider("value", 255);
    $rel.find(".green").slider("value", 140);
    $rel.find(".blue").slider("value", 60);

  });

  $('.container').on('click', '.klik', function() {
    $(".rel-ct").hide();
    $('.rel-ct[data-number="' + $(this).data('number') + '"]').css("display", "inline");
  });

  function refreshSwatch(event, ui) {
    var $rel = $(ui.handle).closest('.rel-ct');

    var red = $rel.find(".red").slider("value"),
      green = $rel.find(".green").slider("value"),
      blue = $rel.find(".blue").slider("value"),
      hex = hexFromRGB(red, green, blue);

    $('.mark[data-number="' + $rel.data('number') + '"] .swatch').css("color", "#" + hex);
    $rel.find(".red_val").text("#" + hex);
  }
});

$(document).ready(function edit() {

  $('.container').on('click', '.ukryj', function x() {
    $('.mark').css({
      "opacity": "1",
      "visibility": "hidden"
    });
    $('.del').css("visibility", "hidden");
    $('.ui-state-active').css({
      "visibility": "visible",
      "border": "0px solid black"
    });

  });

  $('.container').on('click', '.pokaz', function() {

    $('.mark').css({
      "opacity": "",
      "visibility": ""
    });
    $('.del').css("visibility", "");
    $('.ui-state-active').css({
      "visibility": "",
      "border": ""
    });


  });

  $('.container').on('click', '.del', function() {
    $(this).parent('.mark').css("visibility", "hidden");
    $(this).css("visibility", "hidden");
    $("#red" + i).css("value", 255);
    $("#green" + i).css("value", 140);
    $("#blue" + i).slider("value", 60);
  });


});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;
}
.container {
  margin: 20px;
}
.mark:hover {
  cursor: move;
  -webkit-opacity: 1;
}
.mark {
  overflow: visible;
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
  border: 0px solid black;
  -webkit-opacity: 0.25;
}
input {
  margin-left: 50px;
  overflow: visible;
}
.del {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.mark:hover:before > .del {
  visibility: visible;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  left: 35px;
  content: '*', font-weight: bold;
}
.color_picker,
#slider {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}
#slider1 {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.red,
.green,
.blue,
.slider {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 3px;
}
#size1,
.red .ui-slider-range {
  background: #ef2929;
}
.red .ui-slider-handle {
  border-color: #ef2929;
}
.green .ui-slider-range {
  background: #8ae234;
}
.green .ui-slider-handle {
  border-color: #8ae234;
}
.blue .ui-slider-range {
  background: #729fcf;
}
.blue .ui-slider-handle {
  border-color: #729fcf;
}
.da_font {
  width: 1000%;
  background: transparent !important;
}
.rel {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>



<div class="container">
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="dodaj">Add input</div>
    <div class="ukryj">Hide input</div>
    <div class="pokaz">Show</div>
  </div>
  <div class="color_picker">
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: This one also is not working as I want it.
When I click `add` div_1 and slider_1 shows up. I want to show at this point only div_1. Then when I click div_1 slider_1 shows.
Then when I add div_2 and select it (click) slider_1 dissapears and slider_2 shows up. When I add div_3 none of the sliders (1, 2, 3) are visible until I click/select div, and when I click for example div_8 all of sliders are hidden except slider_8 etc. etc. That's my point.|

EDIT: Second works! :) Thanks for help!